# Copying data from Field Test Mode

Tags: iphone

I'd like to copy out some data from the iPhone field test mode. Is there any way to do it? I'm using the data for testing, so it's not necessary to require App Store approval.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field test mode is a built-in application that gathers information on the phone and its network, you can't really do anything to interact with it.

The information that the application gathers is likely taken from the [private API](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/functions.html). If there's specific information you're tying to get, I would ask a more specific question here on stackoverflow about it.

Comment: Thank you Ben! Will look into the private API.