# Copying Cell ID information from the Field Test Mode

Tags: iphone, cellid

I'm looking to capture the Cell ID information and also the variable that is responsible for the signal strength bar on the iPhone for testing purposes. The information is accessible via the field test mode - is there any way to capture and store the data?

Comment: You just asked this question, and received a response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943983/copying-data-from-field-test-mode

Comment: Noted - the answer asked me to be specific though - hence this question which identified the field that I'm looking to acquire.